# XSLT To understand the repetative matching in variable

Tags: xslt

I just to understand the concept of repetitive matching in a variable in the following following code

```
<xsl:param name="privileges" as="node()" select="doc('privileges.xml')"/>

<xsl:variable name="codeps" select="$privileges//privilege[matches(.,  ':[0-9]+$')]/substring-after(., ':')"/>
```

the previleges.xml is having following coding:

```
<privileges>
            <privilege>Access my notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Access draft notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice</privilege>
            <privilege>Access published notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2903</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2413</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2803</privilege>
            <privilege>Access pending notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Access my account</privilege>
            <privilege>Place legacy notice</privilege>
            <privilege>Access my searches</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:1101</privilege>
             <privilege>Place notice of type:2404</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2402</privilege> 
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2501</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2505</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:9900</privilege>
</privileges>
```

Here, in the below condition, it is matching one by one.

```
<xsl:if test="//*[@code = $codeps]">
```

My doubt is, how it is matching one by one or each value without using for-each.  I used this, it works well, but, i unable to understand still.  if suppose, i print the value of $codeps, then, it prints accumulated value such as 2903 2413 2803 etc. when the match is being performed, then, it matches exactly.

kindly help me to understand `HOW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple: When one (or both) of the operands are sequences (node sets), the `=` compares all of the values on the left-hand side with all of the values on the right-hand side.

This is somewhat like an inner join in SQL. Once a matching pair of values is found, the expression evaluates to `true`.

Note that the opposite of this operation is not `x != y`, but `not(x = y)`.

Strictly speaking, in XPath 2.0 *everything* is a sequence. Simple values are a sequence that consists of a single element. Here the above description fits no matter how many elements each operand has. In XPath 1.0 sequences do not exist, but the `=` still behaves the same way.